# Windows Accessibility - get text from terminal app

Tags: windows, command-line, terminal, accessibility, ui-automation

I need to be able to get text from Windows command-line applications. The accessibility APIs for such apps, as shown by `inspect.exe`, don't seem to reveal any text-containing elements beyond the title bar and the system menu (Close, Resize, Move, Edit, Properties, etc.). None of the UI automation elements expose a document property. Also, Narrator (the built-in Windows screen reader) will only read the title, not the content of the window.

Is there any way to get the text out of an existing terminal window using a third-party app?